# parsing nested json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json file that I'm trying to get values out of. One object is nested inside another in this file. I can isolate the top level values, but not the nested values. It must be a syntax issue. Here's what I'm using.

This is the json:

```
{
    "total": [
        [
            {
                "votes": "79,060"
            },
            {
                "percent": "11%"
            },
            {
                "winner": "0"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "votes": "167,800"
            },
            {
                "percent": "22%"
            },
            {
                "winner": "0"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "votes": "51,519"
            },
            {
                "percent": "7%"
            },
            {
                "winner": "0"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "votes": "297,060"
            },
            {
                "percent": "39%"
            },
            {
                "winner": "1"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "votes": "156,787"
            },
            {
                "percent": "21%"
            },
            {
                "winner": "0"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "useWinnerColors": 1,
    "timestamp": "3:00 p.m. April 26",
    "candidateCount": 5
}
```

When I write:

```
console.log(json.candidateCount);
```

I get the right answer (5).

But when I write:

```
console.log(json.total[0][1]);
```

I get Object { percent="11%"}.

And when I write:

```
console.log(json.total[0].votes);
```

I get undefined.

How do I isolate the value of the items in "total", please?

Comment: That is some strangely-constructed JSON. Why is `total` an array of 3-element arrays, each of which contains a one-element object, instead of `total` being an array of objects?

Comment: This is actually a snippet of a larger json file that has totals for each county.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because `json.total[0]` is itself, an array. You need to isolate the specific array *inside* `json.total[0]`. So you would need to do something like `json.total[0][0].votes` or `json.total[0][1].votes`.

I think a better structure for your JSON would be something like this:

```
{"total": [    
   {
      "votes": "79,060"
      "percent": "11%"
      "winner": "0",
   },
   ...
   {
      "votes": "156,787",
      "percent": "21%",
      "winner": "0"
   }], 
   "useWinnerColors": 1,
   "timestamp": "3:00 p.m. April 26",
   "candidateCount": 5
}
```

Now you can do `json.total[0].votes`.

You don't need to create an array where each entry is a name-value pair. You can directly use an associative-array.

**EDIT**: To iterate over your associative array, use `for..in` along with `hasOwnProperty()`. The `hasOwnProperty()` check will prevent you from iterating over properties that it has inherited (some third-party libraries pollute the namespace):

```
var map = json.total[0];
for(var prop in map) if(map.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
   var value = map[prop];
   ...
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know the name of the child node ("votes")? I see I can't use json.total[0][0][0]. How would I indicate that node?

Comment: Than you're trying to use hash without knowing its key, and it's not right. ) Strictly speaking, order of properties in object is not guaranteed, so even some imitation of iterating over them (with `var p in o` loop) will probably fail. And [0][0][0] is just not correct.

Comment: As raina77ow said, you *should* know the name. After all, you're the one who populated the hash :) If you don't know the name, what you can do is iterate over them. Although order is not guaranteed, you can access each property and its value. Check out my edit.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Where did `map` and `prop` come from? I'm trying to do something pretty similar but I'm not sure what values I need to put where.

Comment: @kgrote `map` and `prop` are just variable names that I used.

Answer (score 3):

Each '[' symbol means we deal with Array, each '{' - with Object. So `json.total` is actually an array of arrays of objects (though each inner object is just a 'tuple' - single key-value pair.

So...

`json.total[0][1]` - evaluates to { 'percent': '11%' }

`json.total[0]['votes']` - evaluates to nothing (undefined), as one step is skipped. ) It really should be `json.total[0][n].votes` or `json.total[0][n]['votes']`. These two forms are (almost) identical. )